# Загрузка div с другого сайта на свой контент

Tags: html, java

На сайт нужно вставить курсы валют. Данные поступают с другого сайта(не web-service). Там на сайте они находятся на определенном div. Вопрос: как загрузить этот div на мой сайт, чтобы при загрузке страницы курсы синхронизировались?

Comment: Если хочешь на Java, то гугли AJAX.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Делай типа такого

```
$url = file_get_contents(http://bla-bla.bla);
preg_match("/<div.*?>(.*?)<\/div>/is", $url, $resul);
print_r($resul);
```

В `<div.*?>` пропиши основное например ID дива. Выведи всё это `print_r($resul);` и посмотришь результат

Answer (score 0):

С помощью [`file_get_contents(URL)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) можно получить html-код страницы. А из него уже можно получить код div'а и, если надо, обработать его и записать нужные значения в БД.